# Oracle Service Bus - how to find who is sending in junk messages

Tags: osb

I know nothing of Oracle Service Bus. In our Splunk logs, there are about 12K OSB errors logged everyday, "XML Message Validation Error". I have access to the OSB Console, Enterprise Manager and WebLogic Consoles, and the XML files that make up a "service", such as the producer and consumer pipelines, proxies, input/output xqueries and bix file.

After spending a few hours looking at these things, I'm still wondering: is there something that can tell me the source of the messages? I would like to kindly tell it to stop it.

**Update**: found instructions for enabling 'Message Tracing', and ran that for a couple minutes (starting at 15:35). I checked Splunk and the error  occurred at 15:36. Our sys-admin found the diagnostic logs which start around 15:37??? Is there some kind of delay after enabling message tracing, does it take a few minutes to start or something?